# Get MediaStore.Images.Media._ID by using Content URI

Tags: java, android

I have just saved a photo in the gallery using the camera and I have the content Uri which looks like:

```
Uri contentUriOfPhoto = content://com.example.photorq.provider/external_files/Pictures/Photorq/IMG_20180105_231322.jpg
```

Now I would like to get the MediaStore.Images.Media._ID of this image.

This is what I've been trying to use, but I cannot select the columns for some reason:

```
public String getIdFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  columns, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                int dataColumnId = cursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
                Log.v(TAG,""+cursor);
                return cursor.getInt(dataColumnId);
            }

            return -1;

        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I call the above code like:
`getIdFromUri(contentUriOfPhoto)`

I get an error saying that I selected 0 columns. Is there something wrong in how I query the data?

Edit:

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                currentUserPhoto = savePhotoToExternalStorage();
                                if (currentUserPhoto != null) {
                                    Log.v(TAG, "Will take photo now"+currentUserPhoto.getAbsolutePath()+" "+getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                                    takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                    currentUserPhotoUri = 
FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", currentUserPhoto);
                                    Log.v(TAG,"My photo is: "+currentUserPhotoUri);
                                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, currentUserPhotoUri);
                                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                                }
                        }
```

and the OnActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            File f = new File(currentUserPhoto.getAbsolutePath());
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            Log.v(TAG,"First uri "+contentUri+" second uri "+ currentUserPhotoUri);
            Log.v(TAG,"Saved file image to gallery and id is"+ getIdFromURI(this, currentUserPhotoUri));
        }
    }
```

Here is the method which creates the file in which the photo will be saved:

```
private static File savePhotoToExternalStorage(){
        File fileStorageDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Photorq");

        if (!fileStorageDirectory.exists()){
            if (!fileStorageDirectory.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        return new File(fileStorageDirectory.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }
```

Comment: `just saved a photo in the gallery`. Can you tell what you did?

Comment: `and I have the content Uri`. How did you obtain that uri?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post now

Comment: I do not understand your code. Before you start the intent to let the user take a picture you save a picture with `currentUserPhoto = savePhotoToExternalStorage();`. `What kind of photo are you saving?

Comment: `I call the above code like: getIdFromUri(contentUriOfPhoto)`. Not possible as you declared the function like `getIdFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri)`.

Comment: And when and from where do you call that function?

Comment: Ok. My bad. I posted a sample and then another part and forgot to edit it. I'll do that now.

Comment: I edited it. You can see that I simply log the id from the onActivityResult. I don't use it anywhere else for now.

Comment: I do not understand why you meed an id of a file which is all yours. But anyhow, you can not request that in onActivityResult() as the media store does not know anything of your file yet. You only send a broadcast to scan it. But the actual scan will only be done long after onActivityResult has finished. But agin: why do you need an id of your own file? And what would you get?

Comment: I have a database in which I save the exif data and as a composed primary key I use the filename and the id as I don't want to have 2 files replace one another. And when you first enter the app you can browse all of the images, and I use a cursor to get them. Therefore I have access to the ID there, but after I let the user take a picture, I would also like to have the ID of that picture to be able to save the exif data using the id param and the filename. But yes, I do understand the broadcast problem now. Do you have any suggestion of another primary key ? Could you move this to chat please?

Comment: You did not give an example of an id. I have no idea what you are requesting and why it would be unique to a file or your file. As soon as image files get deleted on your device ids will change i think.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. I think I'll just use the filename as a primary key. Or do you have a better suggestion?